# How to compute the gradient for a separable nonlinear least-squares problem?

Tags: self-study, nonlinear-regression, gradient-descent

Consider the case of non-linear least squares regression with one dependent variable $y_i$ and two independent variables $x_{i1}$ and $x_{i2}$ where the non-linear function is a linear function of two non-linear functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ (for simplicity I reduce this to two functions and functions with only one parameter/coefficient but it can be more general)

$$y_i  =  \sum_{j=1,2} \alpha_j f_j(x_{ij},\beta_j) + \epsilon_i$$

Say we wish to use fit this function to some data with least squares regression, then we could find the solution with a step-wise algorithm that alternates between fitting the $\alpha_j$ and $\beta_j$. This can be a useful approach because the solution for the $\alpha_j$ when the $\beta_j$ are fixed is easily found by ordinary least squares regression.

To perform the optimization step for the $\beta_j$ we need to know the gradient of the loss function. There are solvers that can estimate the derivatives computationally, but the algorithms will be faster and more accurate when we can provide the derivatives ourselves.

How do we describe the derivative $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \beta_j}$ of the sum of squared residuals loss function $$L = \Vert y - \hat{y}\Vert ^2$$

when

$$\hat y = F (F^T F)^{-1} F^T y$$

where the $F$ is the matrix of the regressors $f(x_{ij}, \beta_{j})$

$$F = \begin{bmatrix} f(x_{{11}}, \beta_1) & f(x_{12}, \beta_2) \\
f(x_{{21}}, \beta_1) & f(x_{22}, \beta_2) \\
f(x_{{31}}, \beta_1) & f(x_{32}, \beta_2) \\  
\vdots & \vdots \\ 
f(x_{{n1}}, \beta_1) & f(x_{n2}, \beta_2) \\  \end{bmatrix}$$

There should be some simple way to express

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \beta_j}$$

in terms of $\frac{\partial f(x_{ij})}{\partial \beta_j}$

Comment: See also the Gauss-Newton algorithm.

Comment: @JohnMadden yes this could be applied to a Gauss-Newton algorithm (if we also compute second derivatives, but maybe the expressions become too complex) . Although in the code I used a line search gradient-descent method with a very small maximum step size; that gives a prettier image (follows more smoothly the gradient) that's works better for introducing the principle of gradient descent...

Comment: ...A difference/detail in this question is that the parameters $\alpha_j$ are optimised seperately by using the method for solving a linear least squares problem. The question is about how to eliminate these $\alpha_j$ such that we end up with a function of only $\beta_j$ and the derivatives of that function, and such that we can apply the Gauss-Newton algorithm by using a function of only the parameters $\beta_j$ instead of a function of parameters $\beta_j$ and $\alpha_j$.

Comment: Gauss Newton does not require Hessian terms, it approximates them (somewhat a la BFGS) :). Thanks for clarifying your intentions. Just out of curiosity, have you tried just straight up jointly optimizing everything (e.g. not profiling $\alpha$ out)? I'm currently deciding between similar approaches on a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

A related question exist on math.stackexchange.com [Derivative of projection with respect to a parameter: $D_{a}: X(a)[ X(a)^TX(a) ]^{-1}X(a)^Ty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3839203)

The answer suggests using the product rule which leads to:

$$\begin{align}\hat{y}^\prime =(X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty)^\prime&=X^\prime(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty\\&-X(X^TX)^{-1}(X^{\prime T}X+X^TX^\prime)(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty\\&+X(X^TX)^{-1}X^{\prime T}y\prime.\end{align}$$

Then we compute the derivative of the loss function as

$$L^\prime = \left( \sum (y-\hat{y})^2 \right)^\prime = \sum -2(y-\hat{y})\hat{y}^\prime$$

Where $^\prime$ denotes the derivative to any of the $\beta_j$

**Example:**

In the example below, we fit the function

$$y_i  = \alpha_{1} e^{\beta_1 x_{1,i}} + \alpha_2 e^{\beta_2 x_{2,i}}$$

In this case $X^\prime = \frac{\partial}{\beta_j} X$ will be the same as $X$ but with the $i$-th column multiplied with $x_i$ and the others zero.

Below is some R-code that illustrates the computation. It is a gradient descent method that uses the function `fr` to compute the cost function and the function `gr` to compute the gradient. In this function `gr` we have computed the derivatives as above. The value of the cost function as a function of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ is shown in the figure below. The thick black line shows the path that is followed by the gradient descent method.

[image: example gradient descent]

```r
set.seed(1)

# model some independent data t1 and t2
x1 <- runif(10,0,1)
x2 <- runif(10,0,0.1)+x1*0.9
t1 <- log(x1)
t2 <- log(x2)
# compute the dependent variable y according to the formula and some added noise
y <- round(1*exp(0.4*t1) - 0.5*exp(0.6*t2) + rnorm(10, 0 ,0.01),3)


###############################

# loss function
fr <- function(p) {   
  a <- p[1]
  b <- p[2]
  u1 <- exp(a*t1)
  u2 <- exp(b*t2)
  mod <- lm(y ~ 0 + u1 + u2)
  ypred <- predict(mod)
  sum((y-ypred)^2)
}

# gradient of loss function
gr <- function(p) {
  a <- p[1]
  b <- p[2]
  u1 <- exp(a*t1)     ### function f1
  u2 <- exp(b*t2)     ### function f2
  X <-  cbind(u1,u2)       # matrix X
  Xa <- cbind(t1*u1,0*u2)     # derivative  dX/da  
  Xb <- cbind(0*u1,t2*u2)     # derivative  dX/db 
  
  ### predicted y
  mod <- lm(y ~ 0 + u1 + u2)
  ypred <- predict(mod) 
  
  ### computation of the derivatives of the projection
  dPa <- Xa %*% solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% y -
         X %*% solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% (t(Xa) %*% X + t(X) %*% Xa) %*% solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% y +
         X %*% solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(Xa) %*% y 
  dPb <- Xb %*% solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% y -
         X %*% solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% (t(Xb) %*% X + t(X) %*% Xb) %*% solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% y +
         X %*% solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(Xb) %*% y 
  
  ### computation of the derivatives of the squared loss
  dLa <- sum(-2*(y-ypred)*dPa)
  dLb <- sum(-2*(y-ypred)*dPb)
  
  ### result
  return(c(dLa,dLb))
}

# compute loss function on a grid
n=201
xc <- 0.9*seq(0,1.5,length.out=n)
yc <- 0.9*seq(0,1.5,length.out=n)
z <- matrix(rep(0,n^2),n)
for (i in 1:n) {
  for(j in 1:n) {
    z[i,j] <- fr(c(xc[i],yc[j]))
  }
}


# levels for plotting
levels <- 10^seq(-4,1,0.5)
key <- seq(-4,1,0.5)

# colours for plotting
colours <- function(n) {hsv(c(seq(0.15,0.7,length.out=n),0),
                            c(seq(0.2,0.4,length.out=n),0),
                            c(seq(1,1,length.out=n),0.9))}
# empty plot
plot(-1000,-1000,
     xlab=expression(n[1]),ylab = expression(n[2]), 
     xlim=range(xc),
     ylim=range(yc)
)

# add contours
.filled.contour(xc,yc,z,
                col=colours(length(levels)),
                levels=levels)

contour(xc,yc,z,add=1, levels=levels, labels = key)

# compute path
# start value
new=c(0.9,1.1) 
maxstep <- 0.001
# make lots of small steps
for (i in 1:5000) {
  ### safe old value
  old <- new
  ### compute step direction by using gradient
  grr <- -gr(new)
  lg <- sqrt(grr[1]^2+grr[2]^2)
  step <- grr/lg
  ### find best step size (yes this is a bit simplistic and computation intensive)
  min <- fr(old)
  stepsizes <- maxstep*10^seq(-2,0.001,length.out1=100)
  for (j in stepsizes) {
    if (fr(old+step*j)<min) {
      new <- old+step*j
      min <- fr(new)
    }
  }
  ### plot path
  lines(c(old[1],new[1]),c(old[2],new[2]),lw=2)
}

# finish plot with title and annotation
title(expression(paste("Solving \n", sum((alpha[1]*e^{beta[1]*x[i,1]}+alpha[2]*e^{beta[2]*x[i,2]}-y[i])^2,i==1,n))))
points(0.9,1.1)
text(0.9,1.1,"start",pos=2,cex=1)
points(new[1],new[2])
text(new[1],new[2],"end",pos=4,cex=1)
```

See for a historic showcase of this method:

"The Differentiation of Pseudo-Inverses and Nonlinear Least Squares Problems Whose Variables Separate" by G. H. Golub and V. Pereyra in [SIAM Journal on Numerical Analysis Vol. 10, No. 2 (1973), pp. 413-432](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2156365)